# MongoDB: Combine two .find() statements

Tags: java, mongodb, querying

Using Java. I have two .find() queries that I want to combine and get a Document containing the results of both queries. I have managed to create them individually like this. Notice that the queries are on two different top-level fields. The last statement below is a query on the same field with two conditions.

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable = db.getCollection("1dag").find(new Document("id", "10"));
```

and

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable2 = db.getCollection("1dag").find(
                new Document().append("timestamp", new Document()
                        .append("$gte",startTime)
                        .append("$lte",endTime)));
```

I can't find any documentation on this.
Is this where I should use the "$and" or "$where" statements?

**EDIT** is this the way to do it?

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable7 = db.getCollection("1dag").find(
                new Document()
                        .append("timestamp", new Document()
                                .append("$gte", startTime)
                                .append("$lte", endTime))
                        .append("id", new Document()
                                .append("$eq", 10)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will work perfectly.

The query  `db.inventory.find({id:{$eq:10}})`
is equivalent to `db.inventory.find({id: 10})`

So simplifying your query:

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable7 = db.getCollection("1dag").find(
            new Document().append("timestamp", new Document()
                            .append("$gte", startTime)
                            .append("$lte", endTime))
                    .append("id",10));
```

Answer (score 1):

To create the equivalent Java query for the following mongo shell query

```
db.getCollection("1dag").find({
    "id": "10",
    "timestamp": {
        "$gte": 1412204098,
        "$lte": 1412204099
    }
})
```

you should specify a [**logical conjunction (AND)**](http://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/java/query/#logical-and) for multiple query conditions by appending conditions to the query document:

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable = db.getCollection("1dag").find(
        new Document("id", "10")
            .append("timestamp", 
                new Document("$gte", 1412204098)
                     .append("$lte", 1412204099)
            )
    );
```